# Data truncated for column in django migrations

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-migrations

I had a model with a field like

```
from django_mysql.models import EnumField


    AGE_RANGE = ['10-20', '21-30', '31-40', '41-50', '51-60', '61-70', '71-80', '80+'] 
    ageRange = EnumField(db_column='age_range', choices=AGE_RANGE, null=True)
```

I just change the enum with a space inside each item

```
AGE_RANGE = ['10 - 20', '21 - 30', '31 - 40', '41 - 50', '51 - 60', '61 - 70', '71 - 80', '80+']
```

When I was trying to do the migration, I am getting the following error,

```
"Data truncated for column 'age_range'
```

What is the solution. Thanks

Comment: seem like `EnumField` is from a third party package since it doesn't exists in base django, you might want add a link to the package you using

Comment: @daniherrera from django_mysql.models import EnumField